# How would you translate "To be (something) was and will be the best thing that (something)"?

Tags: traducción

The football player Angel Di Maria has a tattoo that says:

> Nacer en El Perdriel fue y será lo mejor que me pasó en la vida.

[image]

which means:

> To be *born in El Perdriel* was and will be the best thing that has
>   ever happened in my life.

So, what if I want to say this in Spanish? :

> To be *Omega Hanggara's brother* was and will be the best thing that
>   ever happened in my life

Comment: You almost had it, so It would have been great if you had tried yourself first with that sentence instead of directly requesting a translation.

Comment: Es Perdrel no Perdriel. El tinturista cometió un error con el grabado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is better:

> Ser el hermano de Omega Hanggara es y será lo mejor que **me ha pasado**
>   en la vida.

because "Es" is in present tense and involves inconsistency with past tense "pasó".

Comment: I agree with this. *Me ha pasado* sounds way better than merely using the past tense.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Actually I want to make a tattoo with my brother's name written on it. His name is Omega Hanggara, and he passed away last September. So in tattoo art studio, the artist asked me what kind of tattoo he should make, I tried to Google translate, but it didn't help at all. I didn't want if I make a wrong tattoo. So, I need it fast, I asked to this forum, and the response was really fast and it's such a good answer! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What he has on his arm is:

> Nacer en El Perdriel fue y será lo mejor que me pasó en la vida

Transliteration:

> Being born in/from Perdriel was and will be the best that happened in life.

Which translates as

> The best that happened in my life was and will be being born in Stone Creek.

---

**What should have been written** is:

> Nacer en El Pedriel siempre será lo mejor que me ha pasado en mi vida.

Transliteration:

> Being born at/from Pedriel will always be the best that have happened in my life.

Which translates as

> The best thing that have happened in my life has been born at Stone Creek.

Also, it should have replaced the other subject: 'Omega Hanggara' instead of 'Pedriel' It is not Perdriel. The tattoo artist made a huge misspell.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Dario. No me queda demasiado claro por qué Pedriel es lo recomendado. Buscando, encuentro referencias de [Perdriel (Mendoza)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perdriel_(Mendoza)) y allí parece que es donde creció ([noticias](http://futbol.as.com/futbol/2011/07/14/mas_futbol/1310624832_850215.html)).

Comment: Por cierto, parece que [intentaste](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/21401/revisions) eliminar tu respuesta. ¡Si te registras podrás hacerlo! Un motivo más para registrarte en el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

The translation would be:

> Ser el hermano de Omega Hanggara es y será lo mejor que me pasó en la vida.

Take into account the use of acute a, and acute o.

I'm assuming that "Omega Hanggara" is a name.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, you're right, Omega Hanggara is a name.

Comment: En la frase se utiliza el verbo 'was' lo que se traduciría como el verbo ser en pasado: 'fue'. Entendiéndolo como traducción literal quedaría: "Ser el hermano de Omega Hanggara fue y será lo mejor que me pasó en la vida". Ahora si traducimos 'happened' como 'pasó' la frase no suena muy adecuada. Yo usaría 'sucedió' quedando: "Ser el hermano de Omega Hanggara fue y será lo mejor que me sucedió en la vida"